# What formatting option should I tune in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to save a whitespace when breaking a line:

```
print("some message. id="
      + id);
```

instead of

```
print("some message. id="
     + id);
```

I've been searching under *Editor -> Code style -> Java* and haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Where exactly is the whitespace supposed to be added? Your desired example has an indentation of 6 on the second line, the other 5... they both seem odd to me.

Comment: Do you want to preserve existing whitespaces? There is no such option, if all whitespaces are preserved, I do not think formatting makes sense. Check better **Wrapping and Braces** formatting options for **Binary expressions** like **Align when multiline** or options for **Method call arguments**.

Comment: There is no option that would allow to automatically align the first character of a string literal with the first character of an identifier.